# Flutter IOS live text feature

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am looking to add the live text feature of ios to a flutter text field but can not seem to find any resources online on how to get this done i have tried adding a cupertino text field but that also does not work the image attached shows what feature i am talking about specifically

[image: Live Text on IOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is termed as optical character recognition. There are a lot of plugins available including a plugin named simple ocr backed by Google ml kit. Search for ocr in pub.dev and use any plugin/sdk of your choice